# How to Swap 2 UIWebView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uikit

Is it possible to swap 2 UIWebView, like I need to swap the address of UIWebView* currentView & UIWebView* nextView?? is it possible?? The main problem is that UIWebView does not conform to NSCopying protocol. So is it possible to swap??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by swap you mean:

```
UIWebView* temp = firstWebView;
firstWebView = secondWebView;
secondWebView = temp;
```

this is perfectly legal, since it does not entails copying the web views, only their pointers.